# Define optional (multiple) datasource in Grails

Tags: grails, datasource, multiple-databases

I am currently developing a Grails plugin using Grails 2.3.11 and familiar using multiple datasources. But now I want that my domain objects provided by that plugin CAN use a different dataSource (because of performance reasons all data can be stored in a different database).

The problem is, that this second datasource is optional, which means, the user **can** define a second datasource in tomcat (accessible via JNDI), but doesn't have to. This is an important point: the user can define a second dataSource in the servlet container and the Grails application has to check if there is a second dataSource available!

Be to more specific: I've a domain class:

```
class MyDomain {

    static mapping = {
        datasource('optionalDS')
    }
}
```

My DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    jndiName = "..."
}

dataSource_optionalDS {
    jndiName = "..."
}
```

The problem is, that this will fail if the user hasn't configured the JNDI name for that optional datasource (because it is optional, he doesn't have to).

I tried to create a delegating datasource instead:

```
class OptionalDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {

    ...
    // the main purpose is to check, if the optional DS
    // can be created using JNDI. If this fails, the default
    // DS is used
    setTagetDataSource(dataSource)
    ...

}
```

And in my Plugin descriptor:

```
def doWithSpring = {
    dataSource_optionalDS(OptionalDataSource) {
        // set default DS in case optional can not be created
        dataSource = ref('dataSource')
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is, that the dataSource *optionalDS* is not available. If I try to read data, i.e. *MyDomain.findAll()* I get the following error:

> Methond on class MyDomain was used outside of a Grails application. 
>       If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or 
>       bootstrap Grails correctly.

I don't understand why, because I can define the default dataSource that way.

So, my question is: How can I define an optional dataSource in Grails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about looking up the `JNDI dataSource` in `DataSource.groovy` and then if it exists declaring your optional `dataSource`. Something like following

```
    //default dataSource
    dataSource {
        jndiName = "..."
    } 

    //optional dataSource
    //let's first lookup the JNDI dataSource
    def jndiDataSource

    try {
        jndiDataSource = InitialContext.doLookup("...")
    } 
    catch(NamingException ne) {}

    //now if jndiDataSource exists we can declare the optional dataSource
    if(jndiDataSource) {
        dataSource_optionalDS {
            jndiName = "..."
        }
    }
```

I was looking for an alternate lightwight method for just checking if the `JNDI dataSource` exists instead of looking it up. But no luck.

Comment: This is a great idea. I modified your code a little, because I've to declare that optional dataSource in my domain classes. And, if that jndi lookup fails, I'll use the jndi name of my default dataSource to create that optional one.